# The largest family of $2k$-subsets of $\{1, ..., n\}$ with pairwise symmetric difference at least $k$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, extremal-combinatorics

How many $2k$-subsets of the integers $\{1, \dots, n\}$ have pairwise symmetric difference at least $k$?

---

**Problem statement:**  Let $\binom{[n]}{2k}$ denote the family of $2k$-subsets on $[n]$. Say a sub collection $\mathcal{F} \subset \binom{[n]}{2k}$ is $k$-separated if
$$
S \neq T \in \mathcal{F} \implies |S \Delta T| \geq k. 
$$
I am interested in the cardinality (or bounds on the cardinality) of the largest family $\mathcal{F}$:
$$
M_n(k) := \max\Big\{\mathcal{F} \subset \binom{[n]}{2k} : \mathcal{F}~\mbox{is $k$-separated}\Big\}
$$

---

I know that each $2k$-subset must exclude $\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \binom{n-2k}{j} \binom{2k}{2k - j}$ other subsets, simply by considering where the overlaps can be. However, I don't know how to relate this to the overall number of subsets.

Comment: Yes. A subset of cardinality exactly $2k$.

Comment: Please clarify what you intend by the phrase : "...have symmetric difference at least k.".  Among other things, it would help if you could choose a relatively small value for $n$ and $k$ and then explicitly describe a $2k$ subset that does have a symmetric difference at least $k$ and a $2k$ subset that does not have such a symmetric difference.

Comment: I do not understand the confusion: I am asking to find a family of subsets $S_i$ of $\{1, \dots, n\}$ such that each element has cardinality exactly $2k$ and the symmetric differences $S_i \Delta S_j$ have cardinality at least $k$.

Comment: It seems to me a sensible approach is to choose $k$ elements, which can be done in $\binom nk$ ways.  There are $2^k$ ways to put those $k$ elements in the symmetric difference because each of them must be in exactly $1$ of $A$ or $B$.  Calculate how many such pairs of subsets include those $k$ elements within the symmetric difference, and then use the principle of inclusion and exclusion to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: Reasonable response.  Personally, I have never heard of the phrase *symmetric difference* before.  So, if this phrase is in common usage among professional Mathematicians, then I agree that my request for clarification was (perhaps) unreasonable.

Comment: @JairTaylor I have made substantial edits. Since I was asking "how many," yes I am interested in understanding what the maximal value of this cardinality is. This is now denoted by $M_n(k)$. Does this clarify the problem?

Comment: Yes, thank you, now it is completely clear.

Comment: The symmetric difference is at least $k$ exactly when the intersection is at most $\frac {3k}2$. It seems likely to me that you will get the maximal number of sets by choosing $\frac {3k}2$ of the $n$ elements to be the common intersection of all pairs of sets in $\mathcal F$, and dividing the remaining $n - \frac{3k}2$ elements into disjoints sets of $\frac k2$ elements each. You might be able to arrange any leftovers into one more set, though I haven't worked out a scheme. But that gives a bound of $\left\lceil \frac{2n}k\right\rceil - 3$ if my hypothesis is correct.

Comment: As Paul Sinclair mentioned, this is equivalent to finding a family of subsets with size $2k$ whose pairwise intersections are at most $3k/2$, which is exactly the formulation of the question I linked as a duplicate.

Comment: @MikeEarnest to be sure I understand, in the formulation there, $A(n, m, 2k)$ will denote the maximal number of binary $n$-vectors with exactly $2k$ ones (in correspondence to $2k$-subsets of $[n]$) with pairwise hamming distance $m$.  Since hamming distance $m$ is equivalent to symmetric difference of cardinality $m$, it appears that the answer to my question is $M_n(k) = \sum_{m \geq k} A(n, m, 2k)$, is this "translation" correct?

Comment: @DrewBrady No, the answer to your question is just $A(n,k,2k)$. For a constant weight code with distance $d$, the pairwise Hamming distance is always at most $d$, not exactly $d$.